# AWS S3 Bucket Policy throws Access Denied Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policy, bucket

As per the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html --> I was trying to create and host a static page on AWS S3. But I'm having trouble providing public access to my bucket using bucket policy.

So, as soon as I paste

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-name.com/*"]
    }]
}
```

it's throwing me access denied error.

in IAM, to my user id, I have associated below custom policy, but still, I'm getting the error message.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-name.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-name.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also linked this policy to my user name as well as role. 
While creating the bucket, my "block public access"  looks like this. 
[image: Block Public Access]
Also my ACL button I have provided public access to "List only".
[image: ACL]

So, can anyone help me what I'm missing here, I have looked into the different proposal provided here, still no luck. Can anyone give me any direction, like without getting lost?

Comment: If you are seeing 'access denied' when you are trying to assign the bucket policy then that's because you need more permissions than shown in the VisualEditor0 policy. That policy is suitable for listing and accessing objects in bucket, not for modifying policies on buckets.

Comment: @jarmod, I understand what you saying, so I have given s3:* which didn't work. So, I end of deleting the policy and attach AmazonS3FullAccess policy to my admin user. Still no luck. Any other thought, I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You only assigned yourself permissions to edit content in the bucket. For a list of rights see the [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-bucket-subresources).

You at least want to add `s3:PutBucketPolicy` to the list of your user permissions. But `s3:PutBucketAcl` and `s3:PutBucketWebsite` might also be useful.

Personally, i would likely just give `s3:*` to the user setting this up, or you might end up hitting this stumbling block again.

Comment: I did add s3.* didn't work, so at the end, I have added AmazonS3FullAccess policy to my admin account, still, S3 throwing the error "Access Denied" while adding  "s3: GetObject" action to my bucket-name/* in the bucket policy. I also checked the canonical id which owns the bucket is the same as IAM user . So I don't understand why adding the bucket policy wil end up in "Access Denied" error. when im using the same admin user all along.

Comment: If s3:* is still giving you issues it's because your resource arn is wrong. Note that IAM permission updates might take a few minutes to kick in. If you look at the AmazonS3FullAccess, it is basically s3:* but without the resource constraint. So maybe you had a typo in your bucket arn?

Comment: there is no typo in bucket ARN. Even I deleted and recreated multiple times the bucket. However, I got rid of the error Access denied by simply replacing ` principal from Any` to `principal: {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:user/username"}` now the error is gone. but now I get access denied message after clicking static website. I will post my question in the different post however, for the moment this issue solved by adding a specific username to access the S3. But still can't see the public access on permission tab. But don't know or clue if this is the right way.